# Visual Studio 2008 64 bit Deployment Project does not deploy 64 bit VC90 merge modules as expected

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am currently working on a 64 bit installer for a 64 bit binary for Microsoft Windows 2008. One of the prerequisites is the microsoft visual c++ 2008 runtime libraries and it cannot be installed using the Microsoft redistributable packages. I have learned around merge modules used into Microsoft Visual studio and have included these four :

Microsoft_VC90_ATL_x86_x64.msm
Microsoft_VC90_CRT_x86_x86.msm
policy_9_0_Microsoft_VC90_ATL_x86_64.msm
policy_9_0_Microsoft_VC90_ATL_x86_64.msm

However when I attempt when I attempt to install the 64 bit installer on a Windows 2008 R2 64 bit box I get this error (using sxstrace.exe)

```
=================
Begin Activation Context Generation.
Input Parameter:
    Flags = 0
    ProcessorArchitecture = AMD64
    CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
    ManifestPath = C:\Program Files\Nimsoft\Nimsoft Robot x64\bin\nimbus.exe
    AssemblyDirectory = C:\Program Files\Nimsoft\Nimsoft Robot x64\bin\
    Application Config File = 
-----------------
INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\Program Files\Nimsoft\Nimsoft Robot x64\bin\nimbus.exe.
    INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is (null).
    INFO: Reference: Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8"
INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8".
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture amd64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\9.0.21022.8__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files\Nimsoft\Nimsoft Robot x64\bin\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files\Nimsoft\Nimsoft Robot x64\bin\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files\Nimsoft\Nimsoft Robot x64\bin\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files\Nimsoft\Nimsoft Robot x64\bin\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    ERROR: Cannot resolve reference Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8".
ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.
End Activation Context Generation.
```

Is there something I'm not including in the package or some setting I'm not using?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the dll `Microsoft.VC90.CRT.DLL` could not be found, it belongs to `Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package`, you could download the package [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092), then install that package and have another try.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to find the merge modules in

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules

(yes, even the 64 bit merge modules are in there)

if they're not then your install of 2008 is messed up.